# Probability of $\mathbf X+n\mathbf Y$ mod K where $\mathbf X, \mathbf Y$ are independent uniform

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-number-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to solve a problem (from Durrett's PTE), and a component of it requires me to find the distribution of $\mathbf{Z_n}=\mathbf{X} + n\mathbf{Y}$ mod $\mathit{K}$ where $\mathit{K}\geq 3$ is a prime number, $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ are uniformly distributed as $\{0,1,...,\mathit{K}-1\}$, and $0\leq\mathbf{n}\lt\mathit{K}$.

Since $\mathit{K}$ is prime, I know that the range of possible values of $\mathbf{Z_n}$ is $\{0,1,...,\mathit{K}-1\}$, and doing a bunch of examples by hand (and it makes sense intuitively), I can see that the distribution is:

$\mathbf{P}[\mathbf{Z_n}=i]=1/K$, $0\leq\ i \lt\mathit{K}$ so in other words $\mathbf{Z_n}\sim uniform\{0,1,...,\mathit{K}-1\}$

But I am at a bit of a loss as to how to show this rigorously. Or this a standard result that I can find in some book that you can point me to?

Comment: Unwinding the definition, you are being asked to show that for every $i$ mod $K$, there are exactly $K$ ordered pairs $(X,Y)$ with $0\le X,Y\le K-1$ for which $X+nY\equiv i\pmod K$. Do you agree that showing this is sufficient to prove your claim? Can you count such ordered pairs (for any given $n$ and $i$) by, for example, fixing each value of $Y$ and asking how many values of $X$ make the congruence true?

Comment: I definitely agree and that's what I noticed when I did a bunch of examples by hand! However proving it rigorously for arbitrary prime K and n is a bit more difficult. I will try your suggestion later today and see if I get any where

Comment: After some painful amount of thinking, I have got it now, based on your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first prove : $f = nY \mod k$ is uniform over $S=\{0,1,2..,k-1\}$

As $k$ is prime, for all $i$ belonging to $S$, $\gcd(k,i)=1$. This implies $S$ forms a multiplicative group of integers modulo $k$. Suppose $a, b$ belong to $S$. $a = a' \mod k, b = b' \mod k \implies ab = a'b' \mod k$. As $a'b' \mod k$ belongs $\geq 0$ and $< k$, it belongs to $S$. Closure holds. For a fixed $n > 0$ and $n < k, n$ belongs to $S$. $nY$ belongs to $S$. Let the set $n \times Y \mod k$ be denoted as $M$. $M$ is a subgroup of $S$ as for $n, Y ($as a,b) belongs to S, and $a > 0$, $ab \mod n$ belongs to S and M. Therefore M is a subgroup of S. From Lagrange's Theorem, order of M must divide order of G. Clearly for a fixed $n > 0$ & $n < k, M$ has at least two elements: $n \times 0 = 0$ and $n \times 1 = n$. There order of $M \geq 2$. Order of $S=k$, as $k=$ prime, only no. less than or equal to $k \neq 1$ that divides k is itself. Therefore order $M = k.$
That is, $M = S.$ 
Now, assume, for a fixed n, there exists **at least** 1 a,b such that $a > 0$ and a,b belong to S such that $na \mod k = nb \mod k$. Clearly the function $AB \mod C$ returns unique value for unique A, B, C. S has k unique elements (k possible values of a and b). Therefore, if a and b exist, no. of unique elements in $M <$ no. of elements in S. Therefore it is a contradiction, and all $na \mod k$ are unique.
Therefore $nY \mod k$ is a bijective mapping from S to S. Hence if Y is uniform, $nY \mod k$ too is uniform.

$Z= X + nY$
if $n=0, Z=X$ and given X is uniformly distributed over S, therefore Z is too.
if $n>0, nY$ is uniformly distributed over S. Let X take the value 'x'. Each element of S 's' can be written as $s + x \mod k$. Only the ordering of elements will change. Hence set S remains unchanged. Therefore $x + nY$ is uniform over S. As $x$ is arbitrarily chosen, $Z = X + nY$ is uniform over $S$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!